# How to add a percentage column to drupal views?

Tags: views, entities

I use [Views Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) to calculate sum of a column.

items    data
A         20
B         40
C         10
____________
Total     70
Then I want to add additional column for percentage.

-----------------------------------------
Item        Data        Percentage 
-----------------------------------------
A              20 
B              30
C              50
-----------------------------------------
                100
----------------------

I know Global:Math expression. But I don't know how to get the sum, the sum field(Total) is not available. Only `[value]`, `[value_1]` and `[value_2]` available for A, B and C respectively.

Is there a way to add a percentage column?
I have seen this question in another page with unclear answer.

Comment: Check this out http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73481/how-can-i-sum-up-fields-that-reside-in-multiple-nodes

Comment: Thanks Bala, but I don't see how using aggregation can help this situation. I need to use this Total sum in other calculations, Is it possible this way? Please give more details, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `php_view` module to add column to calculate the percentage

```
$field_one = 50;
$field_two = 350;

$new_column = ($field_one / 100) * $field_two;
```

Comment: and how you get all the values to make the sum?

Comment: Exactly, so the real question is how do we get total sum of a views field without views_calc?